# redirect from specific request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^something=true$
RewriteRule ^$              http://www.a123dress.com/     [R=301,L]
```

I want redirect ALL (*) request which have "?something=true" to

> http://www.a123dress.com/

It works for:

> http://www.a123dress.com/?something=true

I want rewrite for example:

```
http://www.a123dress.com/test/?something=true
```

to:

```
http://www.a123dress.com/test/
```

so cut off ?something=true like above in first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `^$` is just allowing home page `/` to be redirected. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^something=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: thanks! it works! but why there is space? before "%"  ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?

Comment: +1, but do we need the `NE`, since we are stripping the parameters anyway? Just asking, trying to learn. :)

Comment: Thanks yes `NE` is handy in case original URI has some special characters like `[` or `]` etc.